# node.js - socket.io index.html does not respond

Tags: node.js, socket.io, response

If I start the server and go to localhost:4000, the server gives out the index.html. But the index.html does not load its style.css and does not connect to the server. But if I double click the local index.html document it connects to the server. What is wrong about my response?

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
, fs = require('fs')

app.listen(4000);


function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html',
 function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {...}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet",type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js">></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

socket.on('connect', function(){...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried referencing socket.io.js like this?

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

In your handler function, you appear to be responding to all requests by providing index.html back to the user.  This is why your CSS stylesheet and Javascript files are not being returned.